# Awk: match exact string in line

Tags: awk, string

I have this file

```
a deiauk Biking US 200 G
b kespaul 202 A
c deiauk NY 222 5 Z
```

And I want to match the exact string 200 using `awk`.
So my result should be

```
a deiauk Biking US 200 G
```

Here's my code

```
awk -F ' ' '{if($(NF-1) ~ /200/){a[$1]++}}END{for (var in a){print a[var] " " var " " $(NF-1)}}' file.txt
```

But after that I got all lines.

Comment: Why do you expect your `awk` code to print a single line?  Did you even bother to understand what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Your awk will print i) the number of times you have seen this 1st field where the penultimate field is `200`; ii) the 1st field and iii) the penultimate field. Why would you expect it to print the whole line? What output are you actually getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want an exact match, why not use `==`?

```
$ cat >file
a deiauk Biking US 200 G
b kespaul 202 A
c deiauk NY 222 5 Z
a auie auie 200 B
b nrst nrst 200 C

$ awk '$(NF-1)==200{a[$1]++}END{for (v in a){print  v,a[v]}}' file
a 2
b 1
```

You could also restrain your match with `/^200$/`:

```
$ awk '$(NF-1)~/^200$/{a[$1]++}END{for (v in a){print  v,a[v]}}' file
a 2
b 1
```

---

Edit:

I tried your command, and it should work. Are you sure of your `-F ' '`?

Comment: Yes `-F ' '` is fine in my ituaction. I don't know why but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`, just:

```
awk '$0~/ 200 /' file
```

Or `sed` (`\s` matches any whitespace):

```
sed -n '/\s200\s/p' file
```

A `grep` solution (`-P` for perl regex):

```
grep -P '\s200\s' file
```

If it has to be pure `bash`:

```
while read a; do [[ $a =~ " 200 " ]] && echo $a; done <file
```

If you're not sure if there are spaces, tabs, whatever (`[[:space:]]` is like `\s`, in the `sed` and `grep` solutions above):

```
while read a; do [[ $a =~ [[:space:]]200[[:space:]] ]] && echo $a; done <file
```

Comment: In `grep` it will work without `-P` also, `grep '\s200\s' file`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.
This will print only the line containing pattern. In your case pattern is 200

```
grep '200' file-name
```