# Grep for word stem and print only word (and not line)

Tags: text-processing, pattern-matching

I'm trying to print only a matching word that are found through a regular expression. Below, I want all the `OPENSSL_NO_*` options that are present in the source code:

```
$ grep -IR OPENSSL_NO
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_CMS
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DH
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_EC
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_OCSP
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_TS
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DH
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DSA
...
```

When I try to trim the output by only printing the full word:

```
$ grep -oIR "OPENSSL_NO*"
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO
...
```

And when I try awk it prints the whole line:

```
$ grep -IR OPENSSL_NO | awk '/OPENSSL_NO[_A-Z0-9_]/{ print $0 }'
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_CMS
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_DH
fuzz/asn1.c:#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_EC
...
```

And:

```
$ grep -IR OPENSSL_NO | awk '/\<OPENSSL_NO\>'
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /\<OPENSSL_ ...
```

And:

```
$ grep -Eo -IR 'OPENSSL_NO_[A-Z0-9_]'
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO_R
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO_R
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO_C
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO_D
fuzz/asn1.c:OPENSSL_NO_E
```

And:

```
$ grep -IR OPENSSL_NO | sed -n 's/.*\(OPENSSL_NO\).*/\1/p'
OPENSSL_NO
OPENSSL_NO
OPENSSL_NO
OPENSSL_NO
OPENSSL_NO
...
```

How does one match a word and then only print the word?

---

This is apparently a painful task given how many questions there are about it. Here are various question I have not been able to adapt to my [simple?] problem:

- [awk match whole word](https://superuser.com/q/349104/173513)
- [Awk: match exact string in line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206976/56041)
- [AWK - print only matching field itself and not line](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1459823)
- [How to get match regex pattern using awk from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5536018/608639)
- [Extracting a regex matched with 'sed' without printing the surrounding characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31476/56041)
- [Only return the matched string in sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43133/56041)

Answer (score 6):

`*` in regular expressions means *0 or more of the preceding atom*. You're confusing it with the `*` shell wildcard operator where it means *0 or more characters*.

`OPENSSL_NO_*` means `OPENSSL_NO` followed by 0 or more underscores.

You'd want:

```
grep -o 'OPENSSL_NO_.*'
```

Where `.` is the regexp operator to match a single character.

Or:

```
grep -o 'OPENSSL_NO_[[:alnum:]]*'
```

for 0 or more alphanumerical characters (in any alphabetic script supported by the locale).

*Extended* regular expressions (as in `grep -E`) also have `+` for *1 or more of the preceding atom*. With *Basic* regular expressions (without -E), you can use `\{1,\}` instead.

Some `grep` implementations also have `\w` which means *any alphanumeric character or underscore* though note that in some versions of some  implementations, it's limited to the `A-Za-z0-9` one.

In any case, note that `-o`/`-R` are not standard options. POSIXly, you may want:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(OPENSSL_NO_[[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p' < file
```

(allowing only one occurrence per line; if there are more than one, only the rightmost one will be displayed).

That won't print the file names. For that, you could use `awk` instead:

```
find . -name '*.[hc]' -type f -exec awk 'match($0, /OPENSSL_NO_[[:alnum:]_]+/) {
  print FILENAME": "substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' {} +
```

Comment: Perfect, `grep -o 'OPENSSL_NO_[[:alnum:]]*'` worked as expected. Thanks. I thought I was having problems with a colorizer breaking something, or greedy matches.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` operator in regular expressions means "zero or more", so grep is perfectly happy to satisfy that condition by using "zero" additional characters.

I would extend the regular expression in some way so that grep is forced to include the rest of the term:

```
grep -o 'OPENSSL_NO_.*$' input
```

or

```
grep -o 'OPENSSL_NO_.*\b' input
```

(where in both cases, I added an additional underscore).

Answer (score -1):

I have used awk command to achieve the same

```
for i in {1..2}; do awk -v i="$i" '$i ~/^OPENSSL/ {print $i}' example.txt; done
```

output

```
OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
OPENSSL_NO_CMS
OPENSSL_NO_DH
OPENSSL_NO_EC
OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779
OPENSSL_NO_OCSP
OPENSSL_NO_TS
OPENSSL_NO_DH
OPENSSL_NO_DSA
```

Comment: Kindly clarify why downvoted it provides the expected anwer . Also tested other user answer which was upvoted it also provides same answer as mine